# Layout corrupted when entering from iPhone

Tags: support, code-formatting, iphone

When entering questions or answers on the main site from my iPhone, the suggested syntax (such as code blocks initiated by 4 spaces), is not rendered properly (this particular example will just indent by 4 spaces, but not render as code; another big nuisance is that new lines are interpreted in mysterious ways).

Maybe this is because I'm running an old OS (4.3.3.; and the Safari version that came with it); I don't know. In any event, in case this is not known, I thought I should bring it to someone's attention as googling this didn't seem to bring any old such meta question up.

As an example, this came to my mind again when having trouble with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776998/location-of-destructors-in-elf-files-not-where-it-should-be-c-linux-gcc) today (see edit history).

Comment: If it's not being shown as code, your iPhone is probably inserting a non-standard space rather than a normal space (in your example, they are non-breaking spaces). But otherwise, the main site is not supported on mobile devices; only the mobile version of the site is.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the newlines, but the space thing is weird...

Comment: You are probably right. I didn't even know there is a mobile version. Is it an app in the app center?

Comment: ooh, I see: `view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5fd1e74b-a1ed-47f7-9fe8-d363c658a194/view-source`

Comment: @gnometorule Select the "mobile" link in the footer of the site. But even on mobile, if your device is inserting non-breaking spaces rather than normal spaces, you'd still experience this problem. It's your device, not the site.

Comment: @Doorknob: The first new line is typically ignored, and the line after the new line simply continues after the one before. However, I've had worse: couldn't stop a line in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746114/stack-layout-of-stack-overflows-and-system-call) from - kinda - centering...

Comment: @animuson: Thanks! I will give it a try (and hope it's not as unappealing as the Ubuntuforums mobile app which lacks the flair of the main site :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5fd1e74b-a1ed-47f7-9fe8-d363c658a194/view-source and viewing the source:

```
I register a token destructor function with


&#160;&#160; &#160;static void cleanup __attribute__ ((destructor));


The function just prints a debug message; the token program runs fine (main() just prints another message; token function prints upon exit).

When I look at the file with


&#160;&#160; &#160;nm ./a.out,


I see:&#160;


&#160;&#160; &#160;08049f10 d __DTOR_END__

&#160;&#160; &#160;08049f0c d __DTOR_LIST__
```

You used non-breaking spaces (`&#160;`) instead of normal spaces (). Don't know why... anyway, if you're not indenting with four **spaces**, it won't show up as code.

I don't see anything wrong with newlines though... could you elaborate?

> @Doorknob: The first new line is typically ignored, and the line after the new line simply continues after the one before. However, I've had worse: couldn't stop a line in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746114/stack-layout-of-stack-overflows-and-system-call) from - kinda - centering...

Same kind of problem ([view source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cb91de77-87a0-43cc-832d-0c1ee529f29b/view-source)):

```
From high to low, a basic stack overflow stack layout might look like this (sf := stack frame) - all assuming no ASLR etc:


 &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;
sf exploit_function (=: f1)



sf exploited_function (=: f2)
```

Comment: Thanks. So it just means I should preferably not submit from my phone as I don't think I can easily undo this. As to the newline issue, there's a comment above replying to your comment.

Comment: @gnometorule edited per the newlien issue